# PHP - Working of Cookies

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie, httpcookie

I am facing a difficulty in understanding the usage of cookies in PHP,
Please consider the following code snippet

```
 public function preExecute() {

setcookie("testCookie", "Hello123", time() + 31536000, "/", WebServer::getServerName());
echo "Before Value of cookine in decommission::".$_COOKIE["testCookie"];
setcookie("testCookie", "Hello456", time() + 31536000, "/", WebServer::getServerName());
echo "After Value of cookine in decommission::".$_COOKIE["testCookie"];
}
```

The output that i am expecting for this code

Before Value of cookine in decommission::**Hello123**

After Value of cookine in decommission::**Hello456**

But the output i am getting for the above code snippet is

Before Value of cookine in decommission::**Hello456**

After Value of cookine in decommission::**Hello456**

Will appreciate if someone  explain me the working, i have gone through resources available in internet, but still i am not clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_COOKIE` holds the cookies that have been received **in the current request**. It is not automatically updated when you call `setcookie` to set cookies in your response. The cookies you set via `setcookie` will only appear in `$_COOKIE` on the *next* request, when the cookies are sent back to the server.

So what you're seeing is that the second cookie overwrites the first, so only the later value is sent back to the server. I'll guess you have refreshed the page several times already, so you're seeing the cookie. If you clean your cookies and run this again, on the *first* try you won't see any output, because `$_COOKIE` is empty and stays empty for the whole request, no matter how often you call `setcookie`.

Comment: Thanks deceze, it was well said.. Thanks for your explaination

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to change this usage, use sessions. $_SESSION is a global array. You can reach from everywhere (inside class,function) and use instantly (no need to wait next request/page load).