# Date () in Cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I want to put some Date() value in Cookies which I would like to use the same data in other pages later. I do something wrong and I do not understand what is a problem?

```
<?php
$value = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
setcookie("DATENEW", $value, time()+3600*24);
echo $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["DATENEW"];
?>
```

I would much appreciate you suggestions and guidance! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well... what *is* the problem? Your code doesn't show one.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529469/php-working-of-cookies

Comment: Please note that `$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS` is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) since PHP/4.1.0.

Comment: @Sergiu Be aware that the answer you accepted does not really solve your core problem. Clear your cookies and try again. Then read Carlos' answer or the beforelinked duplicate again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS` is deprecated use `$_COOKIE` instead.

```
<?php
$value = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
setcookie("DATENEW", $value, time()+3600*24);
echo $_COOKIE["DATENEW"];
?>
```

**Output:** 21-11-2012 10:17:45

this is working for me.

Comment: Won't work **the first time** though.

Comment: Yes but you can test wheather the cookie is set.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read a cookie in the same page request that the cookie is set. The `$_COOKIE` super global array (use this instead of the deprecated `$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS`) contains the cookies that the client has sent you. And in this page load you just sent the cookie to the client, so it will be in the next page load by the client that he/she will sent you the cookie and you will be able to read it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$name   = 'cookieName';
$value  = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
$expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30; //cookie expires within 30 days    
// Set the cookie
setcookie( $name, $value, $expire );

// Get cookie value
if( isset($_COOKIE['cookieName']) ) {
    echo $_COOKIE['cookieName'];
}
?>
```

I didn't test it..